# When I reload the page my previous comments disappear - something to do with local storage

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make it so that when I refresh the page the previous comments remain on the page. Not quite sure how to do it. Also was wondering how you would go about making it so that when you click on the namebox you don't have to highlight "name" and then write your name, you can just click and what you write simply replaces the "name".

```
//Functions for Homepage
function imgUpdate() {
    var img = document.getElementById("navImg").alt;
        if (img === "Cat Selfie") {
            document.getElementById("navImg").src = "foo.jpg";
            document.getElementById("navImg").alt = "foo"
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("navImg").src = "cat-selfie.jpg";
        document.getElementById("navImg").alt = "Cat Selfie"
        }
}

//Functions for Comments
function clearComment(){
    $('#txt1').val(''); //short for getElement when using j query
};

function clearName(){
    $('#namebox').val('');
};

function saveComment() {
    var ctext = $('#txt1').val();
    var cname = $('#namebox').val();
    if (cname === 'Name') {cname = 'Anon';}
    alert('saveComment cname=' + cname + ' ctext=' +ctext);
    var d = Date();
    var prevComments = $('#cmtlist').html();
    var curComment='<p><span class="cmtname">'+cname+ ':' + '</span>'
        +ctext +d+' </p>'; //span = add things to something  inline
    curComment += prevComments;
        $('#cmtlist').empty();
        $('#cmtlist').append(curComment);
    clearComment();
    clearName();

    setObject('totCmts', curComment);
}



function fetchComments(){
    var inlist=getObject('totCmts');
        if(inlist === null){
            inlist='';
        }
    //display the comments
        $('#cmtlist').empty();
        $('#cmtlist').append(inlist);
}
```

My Html file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Dubya comments</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="homepage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header id="banner">
</header>
<nav>
<button type="button" onclick="clearComment()">Clear
comment</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="saveComment()">Save comment</button>
</nav>
<div id="main">
<div id="dtext">
<h4>Your comment</h4>
<input id="namebox" type="text" maxlength="32" size="20"
value="Name" />
<br />
<textarea id="txt1" class="textbox" rows="6"></textarea>
</div>
<h4>Comments</h4>
<div id="cmtlist"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I do not see you storing any data to the localstorage. You are just adding data to the html. The browser does not store ant html data and the page will lose all the information once you refresh the page

Comment: How would I store the data to local storage instead of the browser

Comment: eh... why would you want to save comments to window.localStorage? since this would be only visible to the user how posted the comment. besides i guess you want to utilize the placeholder attribute for your text inputs: see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: I'm playing about with tbh, trying to get better understanding of javascript. So have you got any links that could help me with window.localStorage or know how I could go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jack, you can easily store data in localStorage using global object like this:

```
// your array with comments
var comments = ["First comment", "Second comment"];

// saving your comments in JSON format
window.localStorage.setItem("comments", JSON.stringify(comments));

// retrieving them
comments = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("comments"));
```

You can read more about localStorage on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)